# Crash in the application in the libc

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-ndk

I am getting a crash in the application in the libc. I dont know the reason, please help me if anyone knows about this crash.

I got this information in the website, but i dont have any shared resources (other than one .so file as library) and this didn't resolved my issue.

http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.handhelds.android.ndk/5089

```
    08-09 19:28:21.523: INFO/DEBUG(860): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
    08-09 19:28:21.523: INFO/DEBUG(860): Build fingerprint: 'generic/sdk/generic/:2.2/FRF91/43546:eng/test-keys'
    08-09 19:28:21.523: INFO/DEBUG(860): pid: 1025, tid: 1041  >>> com.mtrl.android.app.ui <<<
    08-09 19:28:21.523: INFO/DEBUG(860): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), fault addr 00000000
    08-09 19:28:21.523: INFO/DEBUG(860):  r0 00000000  r1 422b024a  r2 4310a008  r3 00000000
    08-09 19:28:21.523: INFO/DEBUG(860):  r4 44f8ac20  r5 00000d49  r6 8085d049  r7 422b024a
    08-09 19:28:21.523: INFO/DEBUG(860):  r8 475b2d7c  r9 430f2ebc  10 430f2ea8  fp 0026a798
    08-09 19:28:21.523: INFO/DEBUG(860):  ip 808882a4  sp 475b2bd0  lr 8085d053  pc afd1cb9c  cpsr 40000030
    08-09 19:28:22.333: INFO/DEBUG(860):          #00  pc 0001cb9c  /system/lib/libc.so
    08-09 19:28:22.343: INFO/DEBUG(860):          #01  pc 0005d050  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    08-09 19:28:22.343: INFO/DEBUG(860):          #02  pc 0003ae3c  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    08-09 19:28:22.353: INFO/DEBUG(860):          #03  pc 0005d222  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    08-09 19:28:22.393: INFO/DEBUG(860):          #04  pc 0003363e  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    08-09 19:28:22.393: INFO/DEBUG(860):          #05  pc 0003438c  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    08-09 19:28:22.393: INFO/DEBUG(860):          #06  pc 0001519a  /system/lib/libnativehelper.so
    08-09 19:28:22.403: INFO/DEBUG(860):          #07  pc 0001525a  /system/lib/libnativehelper.so
    08-09 19:28:22.403: INFO/DEBUG(860):          #08  pc 00013974  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    08-09 19:28:22.413: INFO/DEBUG(860): code around pc:
    08-09 19:28:22.413: INFO/DEBUG(860): afd1cb7c 2b00d004 3001d001 2000e7f8 46c04770 
    08-09 19:28:22.413: INFO/DEBUG(860): afd1cb8c 2300b510 3301e004 d1012a00 e0042000 
    08-09 19:28:22.413: INFO/DEBUG(860): afd1cb9c 5ccc5cc2 d0f642a2 bd101b10 f7ffb510 
    08-09 19:28:22.413: INFO/DEBUG(860): afd1cbac bd10ffef 5cca2300 330154c2 d1fa2a00 
    08-09 19:28:22.413: INFO/DEBUG(860): afd1cbbc 46c04770 1c03b570 1c5d781e 78141c0a 
    08-09 19:28:22.413: INFO/DEBUG(860): code around lr:
    08-09 19:28:22.413: INFO/DEBUG(860): 8085d030 1d0abdf0 46c0e7a1 62026281 46c04770 
    08-09 19:28:22.413: INFO/DEBUG(860): 8085d040 477062c1 46c04770 1c04b510 f7b66980 
    08-09 19:28:22.413: INFO/DEBUG(860): 8085d050 4243eb78 42404158 bd104020 1c04b570 
    08-09 19:28:22.413: INFO/DEBUG(860): 8085d060 69801c0d f7b66989 2800eb6c 6ce9d10a 
    08-09 19:28:22.424: INFO/DEBUG(860): 8085d070 20016ce3 d006428b d0032900 f7ff1c20 
    08-09 19:28:22.424: INFO/DEBUG(860): stack:
    08-09 19:28:22.424: INFO/DEBUG(860):     475b2b90  4000cd01  /dev/ashmem/mspace/dalvik-heap/zygote/0 (deleted)
    08-09 19:28:22.424: INFO/DEBUG(860):     475b2b94  80853c21  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    08-09 19:28:22.424: INFO/DEBUG(860):     475b2b98  00000000  
    08-09 19:28:22.424: INFO/DEBUG(860):     475b2b9c  00000009  
    08-09 19:28:22.424: INFO/DEBUG(860):     475b2ba0  00000009  
    08-09 19:28:22.424: INFO/DEBUG(860):     475b2ba4  418850e0  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-LinearAlloc (deleted)
    08-09 19:28:22.433: INFO/DEBUG(860):     475b2ba8  0026a798  [heap]
    08-09 19:28:22.433: INFO/DEBUG(860):     475b2bac  80853ef5  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    08-09 19:28:22.433: INFO/DEBUG(860):     475b2bb0  80887fc4  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    08-09 19:28:22.433: INFO/DEBUG(860):     475b2bb4  80887fc4  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    08-09 19:28:22.433: INFO/DEBUG(860):     475b2bb8  0026a798  [heap]
    08-09 19:28:22.433: INFO/DEBUG(860):     475b2bbc  44f80620  /dev/ashmem/mspace/dalvik-heap/2 (deleted)
    08-09 19:28:22.433: INFO/DEBUG(860):     475b2bc0  0026a7e4  [heap]
    08-09 19:28:22.433: INFO/DEBUG(860):     475b2bc4  8083ec0d  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    08-09 19:28:22.433: INFO/DEBUG(860):     475b2bc8  df002777  
    08-09 19:28:22.433: INFO/DEBUG(860):     475b2bcc  e3a070ad  
    08-09 19:28:22.433: INFO/DEBUG(860): #00 475b2bd0  44f8ac20  /dev/ashmem/mspace/dalvik-heap/2 (deleted)
    08-09 19:28:22.433: INFO/DEBUG(860):     475b2bd4  8085d053  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    08-09 19:28:22.444: INFO/DEBUG(860): #01 475b2bd8  00011a30  [heap]
    08-09 19:28:22.444: INFO/DEBUG(860):     475b2bdc  8083ae3f  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    08-09 19:28:25.943: DEBUG/Zygote(33): Process 1025 terminated by signal (11)
```

Regards,
SSuman185

Comment: What is your application attempting to do? Are you reading/writing to Bluetooth? Inflating a view? Please give us more information.

Comment: Is com.motorola.android.app.ui actually a package that you wrote?  If not, fighting with buggy vendor software is more of a topic for Android.stackexchange than Stackoverflow.  And unfortunately, your only real recourse may be to install an alternate firmware or remove or disuse that component.

Comment: My application is receiving the data from the socket (from server)which is EVRC encoded and decoding that data. And unfortunately i dont have the development phone, i am working on simulator. :(

Comment: Could you provide a smallest example to reproduce that crash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your support.
Actually in my code i was doing byte to short conversion which was corrupting the heap. I dont know how its getting corrupted even after allocating sufficient memory. After i moved this byte to short conversion to the native layer in the decoder, i am not getting crash now.

thought it may help you guys. So, conclusion is not only for native, even when there is any corruption in memory in java layer also, i am getting the dump with libc. Which was misleading me to concentrate on native layer even though the problem was in Java layer.

Thanks & Regards,
SSuman185

Comment: Hi, I'm facing similar issues. Could you provide an example that causes the issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might get a better idea of where your error is by using the addr2line tool.  You can do something like:

```
arm-linux-androideabi-addr2line -e libc.so -C 0005d050
```

The strace tool may also provide some insight if you have a dev phone.